# Send data from arduino to menu SearchView

Tags: android, arduino-uno

i try read id rfid with arduino,then id rfid will send to android studio and show in SearchView, but i can't to show id to SearchView. this my coding

```
SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch (msg.what) {
            case bluet.SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                bluet.connectedThread = new bluet.ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket) msg.obj);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bluet.connectedThread.start();
                break;
            case bluet.MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String strIncom = new String(readBuf);
                strIncom = strIncom.trim();
                try{searchView.setQuery(strIncom,true);}catch (Exception e){Log.e("ga",strIncom);}
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: `send to android studio and show in SearchView`?? To Android Studio?

Comment: yes, i want to send to android studio, id wil show in SearchView

Comment: Pretty strange. Never seen Android Studio communicating with an Arduino. And where would you see that SearchView on your pc?

Comment: no, SearchView in menu android studio

Comment: ??? Android Studio runs on your PC. That why i said that. And you still try to tell us that you see Arduino output in your Android Studio IDE? Pretty strange.